# Sqoop export error java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:

Tags: java, postgresql, hadoop

I am trying to export a HDFS file (or folder) to postgresql database.

This is the command I use:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sqoop_test
 --username postgres --password root --table data_csv
 --export-dir /data.csv -- --schema sqoop
```

and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(ExportOutputFormat.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ExportJobBase.java:314)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runJob(ExportJobBase.java:291)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:432)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.exportTable(SqlManager.java:912)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:81)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

I have imported data from postgresql with no problems. After process data and save it in Hadoop, then I try to save it back to postgresql but I get this error. What could be the problem?

I am using `Sqoop 1.4.6`, `Hadoop 2.7.3` and `PostgreSQL 9.4.14`

Thanks!

Comment: What is version of sqoop and hadoop ?

Comment: @Shubhangi I am using `Sqoop 1.4.6`, `Hadoop 2.7.3` and `PostgreSQL 9.4.14`